# AS2 Dynamic MovieClip Selection

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip, actionscript-2

If I have movieclips called "test1", "test2" and "test3" in the _root, I can use:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
   _root['test'+i]._x = 100;
}
```

How do i use the "_root['mc']" selection method if all my test mc's are in another mc called layout.

I have tried this but got a syntax error.

```
for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
   layout.['test'+i]._x = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting the syntax error because you have `layout.['test'+i]` instead of `layout['test'+i]`